# How does Vala handle reference counting with multithreading?

Tags: vala

As far as I understand, in multithreaded environment reference counting should be performed with locking to ensure all threads see the same snapshot of memory. But locking slows down perfomance. How does Vala solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Reference counting is mostly handled in GObject (for `GLib.Object`-derived types), which in turn uses the [Atomic Operations](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Atomic-Operations.html) in GLib.  Atomics are a tricky subject; if you want to get into details a good place to start is Herb Sutter's [Atomic Weapons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8eCGOqgvH4) talk from a few years ago.  I would recommend watching the videos even if you're never going to put them to use (and 99.9% of programmers should never put them to use) because it will give you a much better understanding of how computers really work.

The name "atomics" can be a bit misleading; it's not really about [atomicicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), though that's part of it.  The operations are atomic in the sense that the change is either made in its entirety or not at all, which is vital, but the more *interesting* part is that atomics act as barriers which prevent the compiler from re-ordering operations across the barrier.  Herb Sutter's talk goes into a lot of detail about this which I'm not going to repeat here.

For example, think about a simple unprotected reference counter:

```c
typedef struct {
  int reference_count = 0;
} Foo;

Foo* foo_create(void) {
  Foo* foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
  foo->reference_count = 1;
}

void ref(Foo* foo) {
  ++(foo->reference_count);
}

void unref(Foo* foo) {
  if (--(foo->reference_count) == 0) {
    free(foo);
  }
}
```

I'm going to assume you can see the problems with leaving this unprotected because I'm writing a SO post not a book.

The specific atomic operation we're interested in is compare-and-swap (CAS), which basically provides the ability to perform this operation safely:

```
bool cas(int* value, int* expected, int desired) {
  if (*value == *expected) {
    *value = desired;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Using this, we would change our refcounting implementation above to something like:

```c
typedef struct {
  int reference_count = 0;
} Foo;

Foo* foo_create(void) {
  Foo* foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
  /* No atomics needed, we haven't made the value public yet */
  foo->reference_count = 1;
}

void ref(Foo* foo) {
  int old_refcount;
  int new_refcount;
  do {
    current_refcount = foo->reference_count;
    new_refcount = current_refcount + 1;
  } while (!cas (&(foo->reference_count), &old_refcount, new_refcount))
}

void unref(Foo* foo) {
  int old_refcount;
  int new_refcount;
  do {
    current_refcount = foo->reference_count;
    new_refcount = current_refcount - 1;
  } while (!cas (&(foo->reference_count), &old_refcount, new_refcount));

  if (new_refcount == 0) {
    free(foo);
  } else if (new_recount < 0) {
    // Double-free bug, code should not be reached!
  }
}
```

> But locking slows down perfomance.

So do atomics.  A lot.  But also a lot less than a higher-level lock would.  For one thing, if you were working with a mutex what you are doing would basically be:

- Acquire the lock.
- Perform the operation.
- Release the lock.

With atomics, we're basically begging forgiveness instead of asking permission:

- Attempt to perform the operation.

Then we just look to see whether the operation was successful (i.e., if `cas()` returned true).

The operation is also a lot smaller and faster; with a mutext, you would probably acquire the lock then read the current value, increment / decrement it, then release the lock.  With atomics, the CAS operation gets wrapped up in a single CPU instruction.

The CPU still has to deal with cache coherency by making sure that next time any other core (a bit oversimplified since even within a core there are multiple caches) asks to read the data they are presented with the new data.  In other words, atomic reference counting is bad for performance, but it's a lot less bad than a mutex.  Frankly, if you want reference counting instead of tracing garbage collection atomics are pretty much your least-bad option.

Comment: Thank you for going deep into details!